# How to show/hide an entire Group in axure

Tags: axure

I am working with axure RP 7.0 and I want that if I click on a button, to show/hide/toggle a whole chart(Dynamic Panel + some lables).

I can group my whole Bar-Chart to one group, I can set them `hidden` mannualy, but I am not able to name the group or somehow else set them programmaticly to `hidden`.

### How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. **Create a master**:if you need it more than once, you can create a Master, and then add this Master where you need it. The Master is one element you can show or hide at once.
2. **Create a dynamic panel:** if you need it only once, you can add a dynamic panel, double-click it to add your barchart.

***Hint:** you can create kind of "functions" by adding a dynamic panel. then onto the onmove-event you can add your actions, and from anywhere you can just move your invisible dynamic panel to trigger that action. So if you do not want to do the same multiple things from multiple context, this is a workaround for axure not having functions.*

Answer (score 1):

A small update on this topic.
In Axure RP 8 it is now possible to show and hide groups.

Although I still recommend using dynamic panels, since you loose all your applied events when you ungroup the objects.